# Ignore http requests from browser in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to enable my Rails application to ignore HTTP requests from anything other than another controller action.  For example, let's say I have the actions in my controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_charge, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    redirect_to edit_charge_path(@charge)
  end

  def edit
  end

  ...

end
```

I am trying to get the behavior that the controller accepts the `redirect` from `show`, but would redirect a user who enters some URL like `http:\\www.mysite.com\charges\2\edit` in the browser address window to some other location (e.g. `'\'`)

Comment: Redirect simply does another HTTP request, in this case, to the edit action.

Answer (score 0):

So in your controller you can do

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to "/"}
    format.json { render json: @json }
  end
end
```

then you can set your other actions to request json(or any other format besides html for that matter).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it seems to handle redirects from other controller actions by also routing them to "/".  What I am looking for is a solution which will result in `edit.html.erb` being rendered when the redirect from `edit` occurs, but '\' when someone just types `\charges\n\edit` in the browser URL bar.  (Also, I had to include the `redirect_to "\"` in `{}` - I am using Rails 4.2.6)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Leito said, the browser will hit your initial controller action and Rails will respond with either a 301 or 302 and a Location header that will tell the browser the new url to hit. So both requests will come from the browser. Plus, I don't believe there is a header or anything that is present on the second request that could let you know definitely that the request was a result of a redirect.

One way you can see if your user was redirected is to set a cookie for them and when they hit your redirect controller action, then check for that cookie in the route that they are being redirected to. This will kind of tell you that they hit the redirect route first. Then of course you would have to delete that cookie in the last route.

I do think you should look at other options first though because this seems kind of hacky. I bet there is a better solution to your problem.